# Henselian ring which is not complete

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, hensels-lemma

Henselian ring is defined as a local ring which has the property that Hensel's lemma holds.

I understand that completeness is sufficient condition to be Henselian,
but is not necessary condition.

So, there should be example of a local ring which is Henselian, but not complete.

I would like to know such examples.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suppose you could take all elements of $\Bbb Z_p$ that were algebraic over $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The henselization of the $p$-adic integers is an example, and also $k[x^{1/2}, x^{1/4}, x^{1/8},\ldots]/(x)$.

Comment: The [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=150&L=143) has those two and two more.

Comment: You meant the strict hensilization (ie.  $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^n-1}]$)

Comment: $k[x^{1/2}, x^{1/4}, x^{1/8},\ldots]/(x)$ is Henselian because it is a quotient of $\bigcup_{n\ge 1} k[[x^{1/2^n}]]$ which is Henselian, being an union of henselian DVR?

Comment: @reuns oh? I did not know there is more than that one.  That’s the one I mean, yes. I was expecting it to be unique but I do not know much about henselizations at all, really. What else can it be?

Comment: To me (at least for a DVR) there is the smallest valuation ring (extending the valuation) where Hensel lemma holds (henselization), and the larger one with separably closed residue field (strict hensilization). But I'm not too much confortable with how it generalizes to local rings.